# 2006 Scion XB using one liter of oil every 500 miles

Tags: toyota, oil, car, oil-leak, scion

My 2006 Scion XB is very old with 222000 miles on it. It is going through oil very quickly. It uses an entire liter of oil every 500 miles. What is the problem here. Is this too expensive to fix, or is it too big of a problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it leaking on the ground? Are you seeing blue smoke from the tail pipe? Do you see oil condensation on the body near where the exhaust exits from the rear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of places oil can leak.
Losing that much oil sounds like like it is certainly an oil leak and unlikely due to blow-by.

If you are not confident in diagnosing and replacing seals yourself you will need a mechanic to do this.
Look under and around the engine for places that look gunked up/really dirty, this will be the area the oil is leaking.

Leaks can typically come from the following places but is not
    limited to them.

1. Rear Main Seal (Big seal on engine crankshaft on
   the side facing the transmission).
2. Front Main Seal (Opposite side of
   engine)
3. Camshaft seals (Smaller seals that seal against the
   camshafts at the front of the engine)
4. Valve Cover Gasket (Large
   sealing gasket used to seal the valve cover to the cylinder head)
5. Oil pan gasket (Large seal that seals the Oil pan to the Engine Block)

There could also be a leaking oil line or etc if it has any external oil feeds (for turbos, or for Variable Valve systems).
There could also be a crack in an oil galley.